# Perl Ternary statement with regex as one of its results

Tags: regex, perl, ternary

I currently have the following code:

```
my $class = $rs->{'CLS_ID'};
$class =~ s/^C\S{1,3}\s+// if ($transform);
```

This works fine, but I was wondering if those 2 statements could be combined into a single ternary expression?

Comment: Sometimes it's more important to have code that is easy to read. The guy who comes after you will thank you (or probably just curse you less :)). My suggestion is to leave it as it is.

Comment: As a wise man once said: "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?" - Brian Kernighan

Answer (score 3):

The ternary conditional operator lets you specify a test and two values.

E.g.

```
my $value = somecondition ? value-if-true : value-if-false;
```

Now, you aren't doing that with your example - you're setting a value, then running a subroutine (regex) if your condition is true.

So I'd suggest whilst you possibly could, you're subverting the notion of what a ternary operator is for. And you'd still have your assignment on both 'sides' of the expression.

E.g:

```
my $class = ($transform) ? $rs->{'CLS_ID'} : $rs->{'CLS_ID'} =~ s/^C\S{1,3}\s+//r;
```

The 'r' flag tells your regex to 'return' the modified value, without modifying the original. But I wouldn't do this, because it makes what you're doing less clear.

Note that the `r` modifier to regex applies to perl 5.14 onwards.

Comment: While this is correct, it's incredibly illegible in just one line.

Comment: Agreed. Even line splitting - it's still not that easy to read, and I'll happily sacrifice a few bytes to make it explicit. A future maintenance programmer might be very grumpy about it. There's even good odds that future maintenance programmer will be me.

Comment: Good point. I routinely have to wrestle with 5.8, so that's worth adding.

Answer (score 2):

Not with a conditional operator, but I think you're looking for this:

```
(my $class = 'initial-val') =~ s/something// if ($transform);
```

**NOTE**: This is officially undefined behaviour, and has very weird side effects. I'll leave it here, though, as a example of what not to do.

---

Another way it could be accomplished (assuming `$transform` is either `0` or `1`):

```
use strict;

my $rs = {'CLS_ID' => 'Cabc    and this should be left'};

# True value
my $transform = 1;
my $class = (($transform.$rs->{'CLS_ID'}) =~ s/^(1C\S{1,3}\s+)|0//r);
print $class . "\n";

# False value
my $transform = 0;
my $class = (($transform.$rs->{'CLS_ID'}) =~ s/^(1C\S{1,3}\s+)|0//r); 
print $class . "\n";
```

This prints:

```
and this should be left
Cabc    and this should be left
```

But... **please don't do this ;)**

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for! This still feels like a ternary operation to me (it has a test condition and a value if the condition is true and one when the condition is false)...

Comment: if `$transform` is false this will give a warning because `$class` is not defined. `(my $foo = 'bar') =~ s/a//g if (0); say $foo;` gives _Use of unitialized value `$foo` in say..._

Comment: @simbabque  - that's true, I noticed that as well as second ago. And I already thought that I actually remember some Perl after all those years! :/

Comment: Ha... i overlooked that!

Comment: I came up with a very convoluted way of doing that which is different from the other possible answers. It's way too complex, though  - see updated answer. Sun is out again, it was a nice excercise for the rainy half an hour we got here :D

Comment: Its worse than "*this solution leaves `$class` uninitialized for falsy `$transform` values*". It's officially undefined behaviour, and what happens is much weird than that.

Answer (score 2):

Conditional operator, and no variable redundancy,

```
my ($class) = map { $transform ? s/^C\S{1,3}\s+//r : $_ } $rs->{'CLS_ID'};
```

for older perl with no `/r` switch for `s///`

```
$transform and s/^C\S{1,3}\s+// for my $class = $rs->{'CLS_ID'};
```

Comment: Dang, someone beat me to it. Of course, the original code is the clearest.

Comment: I am always impressed at just how many ways you can do something like this in Perl.

Comment: @ikegami second one in closest to original.

Comment: You think so? I think it's the worse of them all! "for my? Does that even work!?"

Comment: @ikegami it runs under strict and warnings. :) I'm surprised you're not familiar with it.

Comment: I know it does, but that was my first thought. It's one of those things one thinks shouldn't work. Deep voodoo magic, I say!

Comment: @briandfoy do you have any thoughts on this matter?